# What is the best NANT template for Continuous Integration (CI) that you've seen?

Tags: configuration, continuous-integration, hudson, nant

Hopefully it covers most common targets while factoring in MSBuild, web deployment, source control checkout, configuration management (config files for multiple env)  and Hudson.

Comment: Maybe http://www.caublestoneink.com/dev/?s=nant

Answer (score 0):

Generally there aren't a lot of templates out for tools like NANT, ANT,m etc. Your best bet is to look as the [examples](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.85/help/tasks/) for each of the tasks you are looking to use and come back for help on any given one you're having trouble with. You won't find a lot for calling hudson from Nant, generally it is done in the opposite direction.